# EFI Network error boot failed

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, lenovo-laptop, efi

On my Lenovo laptop with Windows 10 I suddenly started to get this error on boot that says:

```
EFI Network 0 for IPv4 boot failed.
```

To solve it, I loaded the Bios and I saw that my hard drive was recognized.
In the Boot tab I changed the Boot Mode to Legacy Support and then the Boot Priority to Legacy First.

Then saved and quit.

My laptop then went into looping the Lenovo logo followed by a message stating that:

```
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable.
PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM
```

How can I fix this? I don't understand why it suddenly started to happen...

Comment: If it worked before, enabling Legacy Booting is objectively wrong. Instead, just change the boot order, without enabling it. The entry you want is called "Windows Boot Manager".

Comment: In this case it's not entirely wrong, as Windows system disks normally aren't bootable in both modes at once (the standard installer only prepares either UEFI _or_ legacy BIOS files) -- so if the disk successfully boots in legacy BIOS mode, then it's very likely that it *was* installed for legacy BIOS mode and didn't have UEFI boot files anyway. (And if it _had_ had the UEFI bootloader installed, it would normally have a copy at the standard "removable/fallback" path that the firmware could see even if the boot entry had been accidentally deleted...)

Answer (score 2):

Although your disk is recognized in the BIOS, it seems like it's not
recognized as a boot device. Therefore the BIOS tries to boot from
the network, which of course fails.

It seems like your disk has experienced a catastrophic error.
In any case, there was no reason to change from EFI mode to Legacy,
since your existing installation was probably installed in EFI.

If you have a Windows 10 boot media, use it to try and do
[Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

If Startup Repair is impossible because it cannot detect a Windows
installation on the disk, you should first try to save any data
on the disk for which you have no backup.
If you have a Linux Live boot media, this can be used for this.

The best next step in this worse case is to replace the hard disk.
If you would rather try to salvage it, use the Windows boot media
to reformat the disk. Use slow format, meaning not a fast format,
which will take some time on a large disk, but may detect and mark
the bad sectors.
Install then Windows again, then check the disk health
via its SMART data (one such utility is
[Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy))
to see if didn't have too many errors to use safely.

Comment: Actually after looking closely at the Information tab in the Bios, I see that it only shows my the SSD drive but it doesn't show me the other HDD. So maybe the connection is problematic. Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: I changed it from the EFI to Legacy First, because that's what I saw was the solution on different forums/youtube.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the boot order ? It seems like your laptop trying to use the network to boot instead of using your hard  drive

Comment: I have Legacy First in my boot order